# Console shows terminated message in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I run a program in eclipse whose configuration is

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2 
Build id: 20120216-1857
```

I get a blank console with the following terminated message

[image]

Is there something wrong with the build path?

My code is a basic hello world application

```
import java.lang.*;
 public class Connection {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}

}
```

Comment: no need to import `java.lang.*` this is the package which is imported by-default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Terminated means that the execution (of your program, or tool, ...) is complete and the JVM exited. It is not an indication that anything has gone wrong in itself.

Whether your program exits with no error, or with a nasty stack trace, you'll see this message.

Normally, if a program has sent anything to system.out or System.err, you would see it in the console, though.

There are additional suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18504493/366749)

Comment: None of the System.out.println("Hello World") Statements are showing up on the console.

Comment: how did you fix it? facing same problem

Comment: This is exactly what I thought when reading another post. However, it's not correct. I can write a simple program that prints a single line of text, or even a more elaborate one, on my Eclipse Kepler and receive no such <terminated> message.  But if I run the other posters code I get it. Care to explain why that is?

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful for this specific case, but from my experience eclipse will display the <terminated>... message and nothing else when there are build path problems with the project.
I had a complex project with unit tests, and when trying to run then I kept getting this problem. The cause was eclipse "getting stuck" on one of the libraries, claiming that it's invalid. I removed it from the build path, added it back, and all works again.

Comment: Also, this seems to be related to the issue (but didn't work for me):
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197552/

Comment: Facing the same issue. How to fix this issue?? I can't see any output through `System.out.println`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  The `main()` method clearly isn't running, but why?  I'm having a similar issue with a class.

Comment: I added a linked question that have additional suggestions

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Console and reopen - Window -> Show View -> Console.
2. Brute force method - Restart Eclipse.
3. If above doesn't work for you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504493/no-console-output-in-eclipse-juno). Here a lot of other possible problems and solutions are there.